# Would founding a company by E-residency (in Estonia) create a conflict with my Blue Card in Germany?

Tags: germany, blue-card, estonia

As far as I know, I don't have rights to found a company while working under Blue Card permit in Germany.

I've been working full-time with my Blue Card permit close to two years, and I don't have plans to change it at the moment.

Although for making my small side-projects official I want to found a business in parallel.

Seems like E-residency in Estonia (through [LeapIN](https://www.leapin.eu/) or manually) looks like the easiest way to do this in EU.

The problem is I don't know if this would create any impact on my permit anyhow?

Comment: Do you have any reference supporting the assumption that you cannot found a company in Germany with your blue card status?

Comment: I googled before, I can try again.

Answer (score 5):

If you are close to two years with a BlueCard and you also know German language, you [can apply for permanent residence permit already](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/BlaueKarte/blaue-karte-node.html) (after 21 months with BlueCard), which will allow you to register a company in Germany.

Next, even without a permanent residence permit, it is also possible that you just go to Ausländerbehörde and ask them for separate permission to found a company (nach § 21 Absatz 6 Aufenthaltsgesetzes).

P.S. I'm not a lawyer.