# Working multiple jobs on EU Blue Card

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card

I am planning to move to Germany with a job offer lined up, and consequently the EU Blue card, and I am wondering what the rules are on working multiple jobs at the same time. I am thinking of doing some remote work for clients in the US on a part time basis and I am not sure if that is allowed within the first 18 months on the Blue Card. The second job could be a self-employment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlueCard would be only one of several problems. If one will be an employee, I'm not sure if US companies can hire him/her as employee in Germany (then they might need to be legally presented here, or he/she needs a service company in-between). Besides that, one may need a permission from his/her main employer in Germany to work for others or himself/herself in parallel.

However, both are theoretically doable.

- First, it makes sense to get a permission from the main employer for self-employment job outside of working hours (i.e., double-check the contract).
- Second, it is worse asking Immigration Office (Ausländerbehörde) about giving a [separate permission for founding a company](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14430/13223).
- I'm not sure about international regulations about living and physically being in Germany and working for your own company in US --> [this might be rather complicated](https://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/topic/125136-us-citizen-working-in-germany-for-a-us-company/), and one might need to consult a lawyer and tax advisor.
- Besides Blue Card, there are [other forms of residence permits](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11514/13223) (at least 3 for the purpose of employment, and at least one more for the purpose of founding a company), it is possible to select them instead.

P.S. I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Most contracts explicitly state that a second job requires permission of the employer, so this must indeed be checked.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Andrey Sapegin. The  § 21 Absatz 6 Aufenthaltsgesetzes you mentioned in the linked answer seems to be the exact answer to this question. Leaving the link to the rule here for quick reference for others looking for this: (https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__21.html)